# syndaemon -t option not working on HP dm4 running Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: touchpad

I'm running `syndaemon -i 2.0 -K -R -t` but the touchpad still allows clicking while typing.

On the other hand, I know that syndaemon is working correctly because I can run `syndaemon -i 2.0 -K -R` and that works well enough.